# mod page speed adding etag: w\"0" to images

Tags: nginx, mod-pagespeed

I'm using mod page speed with Nginx and I've noticed that it is setting etag: w\"0" on images which I don't want (as they are set by other services).

I found the following configuration for Apache which apparently fixes this:

```html
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|js|css)$">
   Header unset Etag
   Header set Cache-control "public, max-age=600"
</FilesMatch>
```

Is there an Nginx equivalent to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Found the Nginx equivalent eventually:

```html
location /mod_pagespeed_example {
  location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|js|css)$ {
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=600";
  }
}
```

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-cache-extend